# SCUT for balancing multiclass dataset

Tags: r

I am going to implement SCUT algorithm to balance my multiclass dataset and I got this error

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HUz7.png) Error in apply(T, 2, max) : dim(X) must have a positive length

```
library(EMCluster, quietly = TRUE)
    library("lattice", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.2/library")
    library(grid)
    library(DMwR)
    CoronaryEvent <-data$CoronaryEvent
    class <- unique(CoronaryEvent)
    for(i in 2:length(unique(CoronaryEvent))-1){
      for(j in (i+1):length(unique(CoronaryEvent))){
        print(paste(i,j,sep=","))
        print(paste(class[i],class[j],sep=","))
        coronaryEvent equal to class i and class j
        class_i <- factor(as.factor(class[i]))
        class_j <- factor(as.factor(class[j]))

        a<-data[match(as.character(data$CoronaryEvent), class_i, nomatch = FALSE), ]
        a$CoronaryEvent <-as.factor(class_i)
        b<-data[match(as.character(data$CoronaryEvent), class_j, nomatch = FALSE), ]
        b$CoronaryEvent <-as.factor(class_j)
       D <- rbind(a,b)
       str(D)
      print(nrow(D))
      #oversampling binary dataset (minority class till reach 36 observations)
        m<-36
        if((nrow(a)<m)|(nrow(b)<m)){
          n<-nrow(a)
          perc = as.integer((m/n)*100)
          print(perc)
          newData <- SMOTE(CoronaryEvent ~ .,  D, perc.over = perc,perc.under = 50)
          print("oversampling")
          str(newData)
        }

        #undersampling majority class till 32 observations using EM algorithm
        else if((nrow(a)>m)|(nrow(b)>m)){
        print("undersampling")

        }


      }
    }
```

The picture below contains the SCUT algorithm

[image]

For more details see this link:
 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301453161_SCUT_Multi-Class_Imbalanced_Data_Classification_using_SMOTE_and_Cluster-based_Undersampling

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I just released a package on CRAN called `scutr` that implements SCUT. It uses the over/undersampling methods they indicate in their paper. Some other resampling methods are provided in case you want to try them out. The API is friendly for custom functions or those from other packages. Hopefully this will be useful for anyone else who finds this question.

[Link to CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scutr/index.html)